# Prevent a Laravel notification to be sent

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I'm working on a feature to send a "cascade" or a chain of [notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications) with a delay between them with different channel. For example:

Email -> (30 minutes later) -> Push -> (30 minutes later) -> SMS

That flow is working good, now is the user completes something or does an action I want the chain to stop. So I stop or prevent the notification to be sent. This is what I've tried, but nothing seems to [stop them](https://media.giphy.com/media/xT0BKCQJDzoTaeQyA0/giphy.gif).

I've tried:

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    if (whatever condition to stop) {
        return null; // also tried with return []
    }

    return ['mail'];
}
```

Also

```
public function __construct(array $data = [])
{
    if (whatever condition to stop) {
        exit; // are you desperate, bruh?
    }
}
```

Is there something super obvious I'm not seeing? Might be related to our custom scheduler, tho.
Do you have an idea where can I break the app to prevent the notification to be sent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, this was enough:

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    if (whatever condition to stop) {
        return [];
    }

    return ['mail'];
}
```

The problem was something else, Docker was showing me a cached version of the files, so they were always returning a `return ['mail'];`