# Prohibit Laravel 8 Notification from being sent

Tags: laravel-8

I have an Employee model which has an email address. Sometimes if an email address is not available I generate a fake email address which follows a pattern:

7a157358d72a4d4ebcc01cec8d2debae@virtual.domain.com

I also have notifications in my application. Now, if an employee has a fake email address how can I best check if a notification should be sent? Through notifications via() method? Can someone please help.

Comment: Please add some code. How do you send notifications?

Comment: I use notify function in the employee model: `$employee->notify(new RegistrationNotification());`

Comment: Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760231/prevent-a-laravel-notification-to-be-sent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent a Laravel notification to be sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760231/prevent-a-laravel-notification-to-be-sent)

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you!